# Alignment Issue of Tinymce with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor with  wordpress. It has an issue of alignment of text, once you make the text "justify" within the editor then Right, Left and Center alignment does not work for the text in the editor.

Even you can check it in wordpress "Add new" page editor.

Comment: Please be more specific or otherwise the problem can not be reproduced.

Comment: Please Give the code snippet here.